# Peak load using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, worker

I am creating a web application using Node.js, socket.io & express modules. and I would like to find out concerning peak loads on server. Every user make 5-7 request per second.
**Server:
 RAM 2GB
 CPU 2x2 GHz**

How much connections can this server process?
Is it necessary to use Web Workers?

What recommendations can give concerning high load or maybe you know some statistic information.

Comment: Test it.. those specs don't really mean anything since we don't know application complexity.

Comment: you should be able to handle at least 1000 users, but it depends on your code. one little memory leak or inadvertent closure, and you're going to inevitably crash or run out of ram.

Comment: I think this will be great for you https://medium.com/node-js-javascript/b63bfca0539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost impossible to answer question since no one knows what/how you are going to develop. In case you need a general number that you can compare to your system and case, you can check [this link](https://github.com/Nubisa/jxdocs/issues/61) for single node process, cluster and multithreaded benchmarks for node and jxcore distro.